# I've installed Homebrew to setup for my larval project and then I met some problems

Tags: laravel, bash, homebrew

I've wrote this into the terminal just like most tutorials do:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

and then the terminal returns this:

```
Failed to connect to raw.githubusercontent.com port 443: Connection refused
```

and then I tried to do this:

```
export https_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:8090 http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:8090 all_proxy=socks5://127.0.0.1:809
```

the last error didn't show up again but the terminal returns this:curl:

```
curl: (56) Received HTTP code 302 from proxy after CONNECT
```

when I type `brew -v` the terminal says that

```
Homebrew 3.2.0
Homebrew/homebrew-core (no Git repository)
Homebrew/homebrew-cask (git revision f2ce12c029; last commit 2021-07-02)
```

and the `brew install` still doesn't work
for example I've tried to install php, it returns this:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/': Received HTTP code 302 from proxy after CONNECT
fatal: ambiguous argument 'refs/remotes/origin/master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
Error: No available formula or cask with the name "php".
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Warning: Error searching on GitHub: curl failed!   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (56) Received HTTP code 302 from proxy after CONNECT

Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

Anyone know how to fix this? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You homebrew installation failed. `Homebrew/homebrew-core` has not been setup.  Uninstall Homebrew and reinstall it.